# Singular value decomposition approximation

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, svd

I was asked in school to do a SVD on the matrix:

```
A = [1 3 1 2;
     0 2 1 4; 
     6 5 2 1]
```

and then: calculate an approximation of A called A_hat by setting the third singular value σ_3 to zero.

I have done the SVD, but I'm kind of clueless about the second part. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Just poke a zero into the S matrix at the right position and multiply to get A-hat, or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: @harold (Off-topic): Nice use of the word "poke" here! It [reminds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE) me of old-time ZX Spectrum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming MATLAB (or Octave):

```
A = [1 3 1 2;
     0 2 1 4;
     6 5 2 1];
[U,S,V] = svd(A);
S(3,3) = 0;
A_hat = U*S*V';
```

This gives:

```
A_hat =

   1.37047   2.50649   1.03003   2.30320
  -0.20009   2.26654   0.98378   3.83625
   5.90727   5.12352   1.99248   0.92411
```

Comment: Lovely seeing you flex your MATLAB/Octave muscles :)

Comment: Heh - actually I'm only a casual MATLAB/Octave user, but it just happens that I was doing some SVD stuff with Octave recently.

Comment: That's ok!  One more notch under the legendary Paul R's coding belt.